# Verifying separation axioms for the product topology $\{0,1\}^J$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, separation-axioms, product-space

Is my proof efficient? I think I was able to verify the separation axioms but I am still not entirely sure. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}$

I wish to prove the following: If $(X,T)$ is zero-dimensional and completely regular, then there is a set $J$ such that $X$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\{0,1\}^J$.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ If $X$ is homeomorphism to $\{0,1\}^J$ then there exists a homeomorphism $$\varphi\colon X\to \{0,1\}^J$$ where $X$ is completely regular. We need to verify the separation axioms $T_1$ and $T_{3^{1/2}}$.

Let $x\in X$ and let $y=\varphi(x)$. Then $\{x\} = \varphi^{-1}\{y\}$, i.e. the set $\{x\}$ is the pre-image of a closed set $\{y\}$. By the continuous mapping $\varphi$ is closed in $X$, singletons in $X$ are closed, and $X$ satisfies $T_1$.

Now, let $x\in X$ and suppose $C$ is a closed set in $X$ not containing $x$. To verify $T_{3^{1/2}}$ for $X$, we must show there exists a continuous functions $f\colon X\to \R$ such that $f$ is homeomorphic on $C,$ $f(x)= 0.$ To construct such an $f$, $y=\varphi(x)$ is singleton in $\{0,1\}^J$ and the set $\varphi(C)$ is closed in $\{0,1\}^J$. Since $\{0,1\}^J$ satisfies $T_{3^{1/2}}$, there exists a continuous function $g\colon \{0,1\}^J \to \R$ and $g$ is homeomorphic on $\varphi(C)$ so $g(y) = 0$ and $f=g \circ \varphi$. Thus, $X$ embedds into $\{0,1\}^J$. Thus, is completely regular using all functions from $X$ to $\{0,1\}.$

Comment: I’m afraid that this is *very* far from what you need. You’re supposed to show that if $\langle X,T\rangle$ is a zero-dimensional $T_{3½}$-space, then there are an index set $J$ and a map $\varphi:X\to\{0,1\}^J$ such that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism. This means that you have to specify just what the set $J$ is and then what the map $\varphi$ is, and after you’ve done that, you have to show that the map that you’ve specified really is a homeomorphism.

Comment: alright, thank you for the feedback Brian

Comment: You’re welcome. Here’s a hint: $X$ has a base $\mathscr{B}$ consisting of non-empty clopen sets, and you can use $\mathscr{B}$ as the index set $J$. If $B\in\mathscr{B}$, the $B$-th coordinate of $\varphi(x)$ will depend on whether $x\in B$ or not.

Comment: From what Henno and you said, are we able to conclude the following? The $f_i$'s will be either 0 or 1, thus we can define the function $F\colon X\to \{0,1\}^J$ by $F(x) = (f_1(x),f_2(x), \dots)$ where $J=\vert X\vert?$ @BrianM.Scott

Comment: Yes, except that $J$ need not be countable, so $F(x)$ need not be a sequence. It **will**, however, be a function from $J$ to $\{0,1\}$, such that $\left(F(x)\right)(j)=f_j(x)$ for each $j\in J$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you @BrianM.Scott for all your time and help. I appreciate it. You and Henno helped me understand this more.

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deduce the result from a very general embedding theorem (proved in Engelking, Munkres, Willard, etc and many other text books):

Suppose $X$ is a space and $\mathcal{F} = \{f_i: X \to Y_i \mid i \in I\}$ is a family of continuous functions from $X$ to spaces $Y_i$ that obeys two conditions:

1. $\mathcal{F}$ *separates points*: for every pair of distinct points $x,y$ of $X$, there is some $f_i \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $f_i(x) \neq f_i(y)$.
2. $\mathcal{F}$ *separates points and closed sets*: whenever $C$ is closed in $X$ and $p \notin C$, there exists some $f_i \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $f_i(x) \notin \overline{f_i[C]}$ (closure in $Y_i$ of course).

Then $e:X \to Y:=\prod_{i \in I} Y_i$ defined by $(e(x))_i = f_i(x)$ is an embedding from $X$ into $Y$ (so $e: X \simeq e[X]$).

This theorem is the "reason" we an embed all $T_{3 \frac12}$ spaces into Tychonoff cubes $[0,1]^I$, e.g.

The crux of this exercise to find such a family of functions on $X$ and check the aforementioned conditions for them.

Hint: let $\{B_i\mid i \in I\}$ be a base for $X$ of clopen sets (by zero-dimensionality) and let $f_i$ be the characteristic function of $B_i$ from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$. This corresponds to Brian's hint in the comments.

Comment: Can we conclude from the hint that $f_i$'s will be either 0 or 1, thus we can define the function $F\colon X\to \{0,1\}^J$ by $F(x) = (f_1(x),f_2(x), \dots)$ where $J=\vert X\vert?$

Comment: @rudinsimons12 not quite, we have that $J$ is the size of a clopen base.